# Why I was able to review 40 suggested edits today?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Why was I able to review more than 20 suggested edits today?

[image]
[image]

Comment: See [1, 2, 3…test. Let’s increase the number of reviews & close votes for science!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/3853934) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/4751173), as of August 4th:

> We've updated the settings a bit:
>
> - When the queue size is greater than 150, you will have 40 reviews a day
> - When the queue size is less than 150, you will have 20 reviews a day

This is only applicable to Stack Overflow, though, not the other sites. While at the moment of posting, the Suggested Edits review queue has only 50 items, it regularly hits 200 or more.