# Why do I get to review more than 20 suggested edits if there are fewer than 150 suggested edits pending?

Tags: support, review, rate-limiting

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284009/349538):

> - When the queue size is greater than 150, you will have 40 reviews a day
> - When the queue size is less than 150, you will have 20 reviews a day

However, I got to review more than 20 edits on Stack Overflow when there were only 27 suggested edits pending, although 27 is less than 150:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, there are 27 suggested edits pending, and I reviewed 25 today and the last one I reviewed was 5 seconds ago. Of course, one can think that the number of suggested edits suddenly dropped from 150 to 27 during those 5 seconds, but that's not the case since even after taking the screenshot I was able to review more suggested edits. This has happened several times the last few days, each day I was able to review 40 suggested edits and as far as I remember the number of pending suggested edits rarely exceeded 150.

What's going on here? Why was I able to review more than 20 suggested edits even though there are fewer than 150 of them pending? Have the rules changed? Is there something specific for suggested edits? Is this a bug? Is there any other reason?

Comment: are you mistaking total reviews for reviews per queue?